# How do I create proper directories for demo and full flavor code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I need to add demo and full flavors to my app.

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html tells me:

"1. On the Project panel, expand BuildSystemExample, and then expand the app     directory.
   2. Right-click the src directory under app and select New > Directory."

I am using Android Studio 1.2.1.1, so when I create a project, it doesn't show a src directory in the project.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the "Project Structure" dialog to create a flavor for your application. I added a full and a home flavors in the example project as shown in below picture.

You can get the "project Structure" dialog through menu "File" -> "Project Structure".

[image]

here is the build.gradle text file for the app module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zephyr.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        full {
            minSdkVersion 14
            applicationId 'full'
            targetSdkVersion 17
        }
        home {
            minSdkVersion 14
            applicationId 'home'
            targetSdkVersion 17
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "File" -> "Project Structure" is the exact information I needed. Thanks so much.